# Firestore Batch Write Multiple Executions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a batch with multiple references to different documents in my database and I want to update them in a single batch.commit, so I can keep track of the count. Therefore I use increment to update the field values. Usually it works fine, but some cases it looks like the batch.commit is executed multiple times. I have seen it updating the fields with increment multiple times and only at the end I receive the promise once and 'Test ID from ref' is logged on the console. Code attached below. It might be connected to a really slow internet connection. Does firebase retry batch writes internally? Or am I missing something else?
I'll be very happy for any hints!
Vera

```
  const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
  const decrement = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
  const batch = this.db.batch();
  batch.set(reqRef, testData);
  batch.set(statsRef, { testCount: increment }, { merge: true });
  batch.set(statsRef2, { testCount: increment }, { merge: true });
  batch.set(statsRef3, { testCredits: decrement }, { merge: true });
  batch.commit().then(val => {
    console.log('Test ID from ref ', reqRef.id);
    res(reqRef.id);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('test save batch error ', err);
    rej(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are processing the same batch in multiple operations such as Async methods, this can lead to this kind of behavior you are explaining. Once a batch is committed, you cannot re-use the same batch and must generate a new batch operation.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever encounters this issue:
The cause in my case was that I ran this function on the client and the system time was set to a future date/time. Once the client's timezone and clock where in sync with the correct time, the issue dissapeared!